# Populate a reactive column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to populate reactive column in a dataframe. Example

```
df
A   B   
24  27  
24  25  
25  15  
29  19  
13  22  
39  28
```

Expected output (based on values in column B. If the value is less than 25, less, or else More).

```
df1
A   B   C
24  27  More
24  25  More
25  15  Less
29  19  Less
13  22  Less
39  28  More
```

Can we populate column C above reactively based on values in column B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the condition `df$B < 25` to select form a vector holding *More* and *Less*.

```
df$C <- c("More", "Less")[1 + (df$B < 25)]
df
#   A  B    C
#1 24 27 More
#2 24 25 More
#3 25 15 Less
#4 29 19 Less
#5 13 22 Less
#6 39 28 More
```

Answer (score 0):

Using tidyverse you could use mutate.
df %>% mutate(C=ifelse(B<25, "Less", "More")) -> df1

Comment: You don't need tidyverse in order to run base R `ifelse`, e.g., `df$C <- ifelse(df$B<25, "Less", "More")`